R error in installing monocle3, package 'sf' had a non-zero exit status
I've been having issues trying to install monocle3 for trajectory analysis of our single cell data. I'm currently remoted into a server and I'm not able to sudo anything. The particular error I'm getting is the following:
`> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

unable to load shared object '/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-sf/00new/sf/libs/sf.so':
/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-sf/00new/sf/libs/sf.so: undefined symbol: _Z16CPL_set_data_dirN4Rcpp6VectorILi16ENS_15PreserveStorageEEEb
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
removing ‘/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/sf’
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘spdep’
removing ‘/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/spdep’
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmpo8MM4X/downloaded_packages’`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue or how to create the sf.so shared object. I'm on a Windows OS and have the environment I'm working in listed below.
Thanks in advance for helping me figure this out.
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-3          ROCR_1.0-11                 KernSmooth_2.23-20         
 [4] fields_16.2                 viridisLite_0.4.2           spam_2.10-0                
 [7] edgeR_3.40.2                limma_3.54.2                EnhancedVolcano_1.16.0     
[10] ggrepel_0.9.5               doBy_4.6.22                 GSA_1.03.3                 
[13] fgsea_1.24.0                Cairo_1.6-2                 DoubletFinder_2.0.4        
[16] cowplot_1.1.3               harmony_1.2.0               Rcpp_1.0.13                
[19] sctransform_0.4.1           glmGamPoi_1.10.2            ggpubr_0.6.0               
[22] ggplotify_0.1.2             ggplot2_3.5.1               scCustomize_2.1.2          
[25] MAST_1.24.1                 SingleCellExperiment_1.20.1 DESeq2_1.38.3              
[28] SummarizedExperiment_1.28.0 Biobase_2.58.0              MatrixGenerics_1.10.0      
[31] matrixStats_1.4.0           GenomicRanges_1.50.2        GenomeInfoDb_1.34.9        
[34] IRanges_2.32.0              S4Vectors_0.36.2            BiocGenerics_0.44.0        
[37] HGNChelper_0.8.14           readxl_1.4.3                Seurat_5.1.0               
[40] SeuratObject_5.0.2          sp_2.1-4                    dplyr_1.1.4                
[43] patchwork_1.2.0             devtools_2.4.5              usethis_2.2.3              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] ggprism_1.0.5          scattermore_1.2        tidyr_1.3.1           
  [4] bit64_4.0.5            irlba_2.3.5.1          DelayedArray_0.24.0   
  [7] data.table_1.16.0      KEGGREST_1.38.0        RCurl_1.98-1.16       
 [10] generics_0.1.3         callr_3.7.6            RSQLite_2.3.7         
 [13] RANN_2.6.2             future_1.34.0          bit_4.0.5             
 [16] spatstat.data_3.1-2    lubridate_1.9.3        httpuv_1.6.15         
 [19] promises_1.3.0         fansi_1.0.6            igraph_2.0.3          
 [22] DBI_1.2.3              geneplotter_1.76.0     htmlwidgets_1.6.4     
 [25] spatstat.geom_3.2-9    paletteer_1.6.0        purrr_1.0.2           
 [28] ellipsis_0.3.2         RSpectra_0.16-2        backports_1.5.0       
 [31] annotate_1.76.0        deldir_2.0-4           vctrs_0.6.5           
 [34] remotes_2.5.0          abind_1.4-5            cachem_1.1.0          
 [37] withr_3.0.1            progressr_0.14.0       presto_1.0.0          
 [40] goftest_1.2-3          cluster_2.1.4          dotCall64_1.1-1       
 [43] lazyeval_0.2.2         crayon_1.5.3           spatstat.explore_3.2-7
 [46] labeling_0.4.3         pkgconfig_2.0.3        nlme_3.1-162          
 [49] vipor_0.4.7            pkgload_1.4.0          rlang_1.1.4           
 [52] globals_0.16.3         lifecycle_1.0.4        miniUI_0.1.1.1        
 [55] fastDummies_1.7.3      modelr_0.1.11          ggrastr_1.0.2         
 [58] cellranger_1.1.0       polyclip_1.10-7        RcppHNSW_0.6.0        
 [61] lmtest_0.9-40          Matrix_1.6-5           carData_3.0-5         
 [64] boot_1.3-28            zoo_1.8-12             beeswarm_0.4.0        
 [67] processx_3.8.4         ggridges_0.5.6         GlobalOptions_0.1.2   
 [70] png_0.1-8              bitops_1.0-8           splitstackshape_1.4.8 
 [73] Biostrings_2.66.0      blob_1.2.4             shape_1.4.6.1         
 [76] stringr_1.5.1          parallelly_1.38.0      spatstat.random_3.2-3 
 [79] rstatix_0.7.2          gridGraphics_0.5-1     ggsignif_0.6.4        
 [82] scales_1.3.0           memoise_2.0.1          magrittr_2.0.3        
 [85] plyr_1.8.9             ica_1.0-3              zlibbioc_1.44.0       
 [88] compiler_4.2.3         fitdistrplus_1.1-11    snakecase_0.11.1      
 [91] cli_3.6.3              XVector_0.38.0         urlchecker_1.0.1      
 [94] listenv_0.9.1          ps_1.7.6               pbapply_1.7-2         
 [97] MASS_7.3-58.3          tidyselect_1.2.1       stringi_1.8.3         
[100] forcats_1.0.0          locfit_1.5-9.10        grid_4.2.3            
[103] fastmatch_1.1-4        tools_4.2.3            timechange_0.3.0      
[106] future.apply_1.11.2    circlize_0.4.16        rstudioapi_0.16.0     
[109] janitor_2.2.0          gridExtra_2.3          farver_2.1.2          
[112] Rtsne_0.17             digest_0.6.37          shiny_1.9.1           
[115] microbenchmark_1.4.10  car_3.1-2              broom_1.0.6           
[118] later_1.3.2            RcppAnnoy_0.0.22       httr_1.4.7            
[121] AnnotationDbi_1.60.2   Deriv_4.1.3            colorspace_2.1-1      
[124] XML_3.99-0.17          fs_1.6.4               tensor_1.5            
[127] reticulate_1.38.0      splines_4.2.3          uwot_0.2.2            
[130] yulab.utils_0.1.4      rematch2_2.1.2         spatstat.utils_3.0-5  
[133] plotly_4.10.4          sessioninfo_1.2.2      xtable_1.8-4          
[136] jsonlite_1.8.8         R6_2.5.1               profvis_0.3.8         
[139] pillar_1.9.0           htmltools_0.5.8.1      mime_0.12             
[142] glue_1.7.0             fastmap_1.2.0          BiocParallel_1.32.6   
[145] codetools_0.2-19       maps_3.4.2             pkgbuild_1.4.4        
[148] utf8_1.2.4             lattice_0.20-45        spatstat.sparse_3.1-0 
[151] tibble_3.2.1           curl_5.2.2             ggbeeswarm_0.7.2      
[154] leiden_0.4.3.1         survival_3.5-5         desc_1.4.3            
[157] munsell_0.5.1          GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9 reshape2_1.4.4        
[160] gtable_0.3.5    


sf.so: undefined symbol: says your sf.so isn't built properly. I can't reassign you to a non-server setting, but you'll have to explore, in a terminal, gdal-config --version, proj  --version, geos-config --version to confirm they are on your server (if not, sysadmins), check that your R has via packageVersion(, all sf 'imports' and 'linking to', then perhaps also 'suggests', get any needed with install.packages('X_needed', dependencies = TRUE), so, basically consider it like setting up shop in a new place, finally, with all its friends at the surprise party, install.packages(sf

And, finally, you might additionally look at sfdep as sf version of spdep. Hope the sysadmins are friendly and work late. And all the necessary BioConductor packages for monacle3.

You think you’re on a Windows OS???? All the actions seem to be on Ubuntu.
